# SQL Query: Combine like records into multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have learned a lot of VBA from this community over the past few years but now I am venturing into SQL for the first time and can NOT find what I need. I am self-taught and have been doing it for just a couple days or so and need someone to help me learn, not just give a solution.

### **My Goal:**

Create a query that outputs one row per "Service Order ID" (SO_ID) and has a column for each "SIO Reason" (SIO_REASON)

### **What I have now:**

A query that returns multiple rows for the same SO_ID if there are multiple SIO_REASON codes.

### My Code:

I start with the a table that holds the SO_ID, then left join several tables to it so I can get all the information I need in my query... here's my code:

```
    Select Distinct
a.SO_ID,
a.SERVICE_PERSON,
a.WORK_DONE_DT,
a.ACCOUNT_ID,
e.RATE_ID,
a.AREA,
d.SHORT_DESC,
d.UTIL_NAME,
b.SIO_REASON,
c.DSCR

FROM
SO_TABLE a

Left Join SERVICE_POINT_TABLE e ON
e.coy = a.coy
and e.SP_ID = a.SP_ID
and e.ACCOUNT_ID = a.ACCOUNT_ID
and (e.LINK_DT  < a.WORK_DONE_DT and (e.UNLINK_DT >= a.WORK_DONE_DT or e.UNLINK_DT = 0))

LEFT JOIN SIO_REASON_TABLE b ON
b.coy = a.coy
and b.SO_ID = a.SO_ID

LEFT JOIN SIO_REASON_DESCRIPTION_TABLE c ON
c.coy = a.coy
and b.SIO_REASON = c.SIO_REASON

LEFT JOIN AREA_TABLE d ON
d.coy = a.coy
and a.AREA = d.AREA

WHERE
a.coy = 1
and a.util_type = 'A'
and a.status = 'C'
and a.type = 'SIO'
and (a.WORK_DONE_DT >= 20150201 and a.WORK_DONE_DT <= 20150228)

ORDER BY
a.WORK_DONE_DT,
a.SO_ID,
a.SERVICE_PERSON,
a.ACCOUNT_ID,
e.RATE_ID,
a.AREA,
d.SHORT_DESC,
d.UTIL_NAME,
b.SIO_REASON,
c.DSCR
```

Here's the output I get, just a three row example:

```
SO_ID | DT | ACCT | RATE | AREA | DESC | NAME |SIO_REASON | DSCR
____________________________________________________________________
11111 |  a | 1234 | xxxx | 999  |  NE  | NEG  |    CB     | CALLBACK
11111 |  a | 1234 | xxxx | 999  |  NE  | NEG  |    FA     | FURNREPR
11111 |  a | 1234 | xxxx | 999  |  NE  | NEG  |    TM     | TIMEMATERIAL
```

And what I want is a single line that has all the same headings above (SO_ID through NAME) and then has these tacked on the end. There could be a max of 4 SIO_REASONS for any given SO_ID so I'd like to have four options and just null out if there are less than 4 (there's always at least one!):

```
SIO1 |   DSCR1  | SIO2 |   DSCR2  | SIO3 |     DSCR3    | SIO4 | DSCR4 |
_________________________________________________________________________
 CB  | CALLBACK |  FA  | FURNREPR |  TM  | TIMEMATERIAL | null | null  |
```

I tried to be as detailed as possible - again, I am very new to this and don't have a great grasp on subqueries and things like that yet. I'm more than willing to learn, it's just an overwhelming ocean of stuff out there and I don't know the right direction to go to accomplish what I want!

Comment: You probably need to look into a PIVOT

Comment: It looks like the PIVOT function takes values from within a column and turns those into column headings, then aggregates values into those columns. If I understand it correctly, that means I would have to have a column for each "SIO_REASON" and then basically place a count inside each applicable column? If possible, I'd rather not have to go that route - but if it's the only option, I can give it a try. My desired output would be the four SIO columns with the corresponding SIO_REASON in each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else struggling with this, I finally did get to a solution that works for me! I'm sure it's not conventionally correct, but it gets the job done! Here's what it ended up looking like:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT SO_ID,
  SERVICE_PERSON,
  WORK_DONE_DT,
  ACCOUNT_ID,
  RATE_ID,
  AREA,
  SHORT_DESC,
  UTIL_NAME,
  MAX(SIO_REASON_1) AS SIO_REASON_1,
  MAX(DSCR_1)       AS DSCR_1,
  MAX(SIO_REASON_2) AS SIO_REASON_1,
  MAX(DSCR_2)       AS DSCR_2,
  MAX(SIO_REASON_3) AS SIO_REASON_3,
  MAX(DSCR_3)       AS DSCR_3
FROM
  (SELECT a.SO_ID,
    a.SERVICE_PERSON,
    a.WORK_DONE_DT,
    a.ACCOUNT_ID,
    e.RATE_ID,
    a.AREA,
    d.SHORT_DESC,
    d.UTIL_NAME,
    b.SIO_REASON,
    c.DSCR,
    CASE
      WHEN b.SIO_REASON NOT IN ('CB', 'TM')
      THEN b.SIO_REASON
    END AS SIO_REASON_1,
    CASE
      WHEN b.SIO_REASON NOT IN ('CB', 'TM')
      THEN c.DSCR
    END AS DSCR_1,
    CASE
      WHEN b.SIO_REASON = 'CB'
      THEN b.SIO_REASON
    END AS SIO_REASON_2,
    CASE
      WHEN b.SIO_REASON = 'CB'
      THEN c.DSCR
    END AS DSCR_2,
    CASE
      WHEN b.SIO_REASON = 'TM'
      THEN b.SIO_REASON
    END AS SIO_REASON_3,
    CASE
      WHEN b.SIO_REASON = 'TM'
      THEN c.DSCR
    END AS DSCR_3
  FROM SO_TABLE a

Left Join SERVICE_POINT_TABLE e ON
e.coy = a.coy
and e.SP_ID = a.SP_ID
and e.ACCOUNT_ID = a.ACCOUNT_ID
and (e.LINK_DT  < a.WORK_DONE_DT and (e.UNLINK_DT >= a.WORK_DONE_DT or e.UNLINK_DT = 0))

LEFT JOIN SIO_REASON_TABLE b ON
b.coy = a.coy
and b.SO_ID = a.SO_ID

LEFT JOIN SIO_REASON_DESCRIPTION_TABLE c ON
c.coy = a.coy
and b.SIO_REASON = c.SIO_REASON

LEFT JOIN AREA_TABLE d ON
d.coy = a.coy
and a.AREA = d.AREA
  WHERE a.coy          = 1
  AND a.util_type      = 'A'
  AND a.status         = 'C'
  AND a.type           = 'SIO'
  AND (a.WORK_DONE_DT >= 20150201
  AND a.WORK_DONE_DT  <= 20150228)
  )
GROUP BY SO_ID, SERVICE_PERSON, WORK_DONE_DT, ACCOUNT_ID, RATE_ID, 
AREA, SHORT_DESC, UTIL_NAME
ORDER BY WORK_DONE_DT,
  SO_ID,
  SERVICE_PERSON,
  ACCOUNT_ID,
  RATE_ID,
  AREA,
  SHORT_DESC,
  UTIL_NAME
```

This gives me an output of:

```
SIO1 |   DSCR1  | SIO2 |   DSCR2  | SIO3 |     DSCR3    | SIO4 | DSCR4 |
_________________________________________________________________________
 CB  | CALLBACK |  FA  | FURNREPR |  TM  | TIMEMATERIAL | null | null  |
```